# PowerBI - Need measures based on two separate tables to sum correctly in column total

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, dax

I have a measure that calculates percentage changes between two separate tables.
This measure is used as a rough way of predicting the next quarter's totals based on new weekly data at the time.

I need the **_*Total*%Change** column and the **_Total_Predictive** columns to sum correctly.

[image: Prediction Table]

**Expected output**

**_*Total*%Change** should be **1.00%**

**_Total_Predictive** should be **7,432**

**Measures**

```
_Total_Table1 =
    VAR _table = SUMMARIZE(Table1, [Count],"_value",[Total(T1)])
    RETURN
    IF(HASONEVALUE(Table1[Count]),[Total(T1)],SUMX(_table,[_value]))
```

```
_Total_Table2(Earliest) =
    VAR _table = SUMMARIZE(Table2, [Count],"_value",[Earliest Total(T2)])
    RETURN
    IF(HASONEVALUE(Table2[Count]),[Earliest Total(T2)],SUMX(_table,[_value]))
```

```
_Total_Table2(Latest) =
    VAR _table = SUMMARIZE(Table2, [Count],"_value",[Latest Total(T2)]) 
    RETURN 
    IF(HASONEVALUE(Table2[Count]),[Latest Total(T2)],SUMX(_table,[_value]))
```

```
_Total%Change = ([_Total_Table1]-[_Total_Table2]) / [_Total_Table2]
```

```
_Total_Predictive = [_Total_Table2(Latest)]*(1+[_Total_%Change])
```

```
Latest Total(T2) =
    CALCULATE([Total(T2)],
        FILTER(ALL(Table2[RunDate]), Table2[RunDate]=[Latest Display Week]))
```

```
Earliest Total(T2) = 
    CALCULATE([Total(T2)], 
        FILTER(ALL(Table2[RunDate]), Table2[RunDate]=FirstDATE(ReportPeriod[DisplayWeek])))
```

```
Total(T2) =
    CALCULATE(SUM(Table2[Count]),
        FILTER(Table2,Table2[Category]="Basic"))
```

```
Total(T1) =
    CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Count]), 
        FILTER(Table1,Table1[Category]="Basic"))
```

**Additional info**

This report is based on an excel workbook which is being moved to Power BI and needs to replicate the measures in the excel workbook.

Table 1 is quarterly data and Table 2 is weekly data.

The tables being two different reporting periods needed an additional dimensional table to help bring measures together into the one table on the report page.

[image: Date Table Relationship]
[image: Report Table]
[image]